# Local diffeomorphism between a disk and a sphere

Tags: smooth-manifolds, surfaces, smooth-functions, diffeomorphism

This may be a silly question, but I’ll make it anyway. Let $f: D^2 \to S^2$ be a local diffeomorphism between the closed unit disk and the unit sphere. Is it necessarily injective?

Comment: How does the local diffeomorphism behave at the boundary of $D^2$? Are you only assuming the local diffeomorphism propery for the interior of $D^2$?

Comment: @Prototank the derivative of $f$ is an isomorphism at all points of the closed disk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, I don't think so. For instance, think about stretching out $D^2$ into a very long and thin oval and wrapping it twice around the equator of $S^2$. This wrapping is locally a diffeomorphism, but it is not injective. If this is unclear, I can try to attach a picture.

You could imagine wrapping $[0,4\pi]\times [\pi/4,3\pi/4]$ around the equator of $S^2$ using the usual spherical coordinate parametrization where we view $[0,4\pi]$ as the $\theta$ coordinate and $[\pi/4,3\pi/4]$ as the azimuthal coordinate $\phi$.

Comment: Sure! A local diffeo in this case is an immersion!